# Best way to cut up a cheesecake into bites

Tags: equipment, cheesecake

I will be making Pumpkin cheesecake bites for Halloween using [this recipe](http://www.tasteofhome.com/Recipes/Pumpkin-Cheesecake-Bars). I already made a trial batch and it came out quite nicely, except for the fact that cutting it into bars was a little difficult. What's the best way to do it?

Also, the tasters preferred that I skip the top layer of flour/nut mixture and this will make the cutting up more difficult as the top will have a creamy texture.

Would freezing it beforehand help?What's the best tool to use?

Comment: It's not just cream cheese. The egg, in particular, should bind it enough that you can cut it.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: I didn't mean that the topping will be just cream cheese.. I meant that it has a creamy texture..Will edit now

Comment: Whatever you do, don't freeze the cake. I've done it and the bottom will become soggy.

Comment: @BaffledCook, good I asked here then, because a lot of people were suggesting it..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My grandmother's favorite method for cutting cheesecake is dental floss.  Waxed or unwaxed shouldn't matter, though waxed may help keep cake from sticking too much.  Just be sure not to get a flavor!

Grip the ends tightly, the way you would if flossing your teeth and pull evenly down through the cake.  Then release one end and pull the floss *through* the cake.  Do NOT pull the floss back up.  Repeat as necessary until you have the size pieces you want.

Comment: Dental floss, or cheese wire...